# ImageIO.read() infinite loop

Tags: java, loading, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

ImageIO.read() just seems to be stuck in an infinite loop.

My code:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Texture {
    BufferedImage _img;

    public Texture(String path) {
        try {
            _img = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Other class:

```
private Texture _tex;
_tex = new Texture("/res/img.png");
```

I have tried loading the image this URL and File, none works.

I am using eclipse, on a mac, and I am using LWJGL 3 if that has anything to do with anything.

Hope you can help me! :-)

Comment: What makes you think it's stuck in an infinite loop? Have you tried debugging it to see if it's getting stuck?

Comment: The code stops when I call ImageIO.read() and continue untill i force quit.

Comment: Not that it is the problem here, but don't read the image in the constructor: pass in the buffered image directly. It makes your class much more flexible, e.g. you can create new images programmatically and use those in your Texture class. And don't swallow the exception, you will end up with a part-initialized class (the image might be null if the image loading fails).

Comment: Could you post the full context of where you are trying to create your `Texture` object? Are you getting an Exception, or is it only freezing up?

Comment: @AndyTurner I am very aware that this is not the ideal way to do the loading, I just created this class to make it much simpler, and to cut away all unusable.

Comment: @EvanLaHurd I don't do anything other with the Texture Obejct, than the two lines in "Other class:"
Creating a private field, and initialising in the Constructor of the 'Main' class.

Comment: I tried reproducing it, but if my image exists, it works fine, and if it doesn't I just get an `Exception`. Not sure why it would be freezing. I would honestly just try to use the Eclipse debugger.

Comment: Do you have the image open in another application while trying to run this code? Maybe the other application has a lock on the file?

Comment: Any updates? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a File, try using an input stream like this:

```
InputStream stream = Texture.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
_img = ImageIO.read(stream);
```

I'm actually experiencing a similar issue, but it's related to the creation of BufferedImages.