# ImageIO.read(); Hang

Tags: java, freeze, javax.imageio

Whilst I've seen some people talking about this problem I haven't been able to find any definitive answer.

In this block, the program WILL hang on ImageIO.read()

```
System.out.println("1");
BufferedImage image = null;
System.out.println("2");
FileInputStream fis = prepareFile("./Textures/" + loc); <<-- "./Textures/TreeSmall.png"
System.out.println("3");
try {
    System.out.println("4"); <<- Logs
    image = ImageIO.read(fis); <<--Hangs
    System.out.println("5"); <<- Never reached
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Unable to load Texture");
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

I've seen the suggestion to use the boot argument `-Djava.awt.headless=true` , and whilst this does stop it from hanging - it just releases this error and doesn't read the file:

```
4
2018-06-08 10:29:42.742 java[2345:45920] [JRSAppKitAWT markAppIsDaemon]: Process manager already initialized: can't fully enable headless mode.
5
```

Here is the encapsulating class:

...

```
public class TextureEngine {
    public int textureID;
    public TextureEngine(String loc){ 
            try {

                System.out.println("1");
               BufferedImage image = null;
               System.out.println("2");
               FileInputStream fis = prepareFile("./Textures/" + loc);
               System.out.println("3");

                   System.out.println("4");
                   image = ImageIO.read(fis);
                   System.out.println("5");


              int[] pixels = new int[image.getWidth() * image.getHeight()];
                image.getRGB(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), pixels, 0, image.getWidth());

                ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(image.getWidth() * image.getHeight() * 4);
                System.out.println("3");
                for(int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++){
                    for(int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++){
                        int pixel = pixels[y * image.getWidth() + x];
                        buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF));   
                        buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF));   
                        buffer.put((byte) (pixel & 0xFF));   
                        buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 24) & 0xFF)); 
                    }

                buffer.flip();

                textureID = glGenTextures(); 
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID); 

                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

                glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

           }
               } catch (Throwable t) {
                   System.err.println("Unable to load Texture");
                   System.exit(1);
               }
    }
        public static FileInputStream prepareFile(String loc){
            File file = new File(loc);
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return fis;
        }
        protected void finalize() throws Throwable{
            glDeleteTextures(textureID);
            super.finalize();
        }
           public void bind(int sampler){
               if(sampler >= 0 && sampler <= 31){
                    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + sampler);
                    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
               }
    }
}
```

Which is called as such:

```
TextureEngine tex = new TextureEngine("TreeSmall.png");
    //Menu Loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
        tex.bind(0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0,0);
        glVertex2f(-0.9f, 0.9f);

        glColor4f(0,0,0,0);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1);
        glVertex2f(0.9f, 0.9f);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1);
        glVertex2f(0.9f, -0.9f);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0);
        glVertex2f(-0.9f, -0.9f);
        glEnd();
```

I tried parsing to a ByteArray as such:

```
Path texture = Paths.get("./Textures/" + loc);
byte[] fis = Files.readAllBytes(texture);
ByteArrayInputStream textureBIS = new
ByteArrayInputStream(fis);
System.out.println("4");
image = ImageIO.read(textureBIS);
System.out.println("5");
```

And using BufferedImage - but it still hangs on the same line, 'ImageIO.read();'

I'm using a Hackintosh and heard it could be a problem with this OS (I'm on `10.12.6`)

I'm fairly new to java, and not quite sure how to continue, any pointers?

Comment: From seeing the rest of your code, I think this is an OpenGL/AWT thread issue. It's not actually reading the file that is the problem, it's the AWT initialization that happens when you use `ImageIO` (or its support classes) the first time. This is also why headless mode helps, as this doesn't initialize AWT. Try replacing `ImageIO.read()` with `new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)` I suspect it will still hang.

Comment: It does indeed still hang with a bufferedImage

Comment: I would like to point out that I have the thread arg, '-XstartOnFirstThread'. This has been required to allow GLFW to work - could this be a factor?

Answer (score 0):

Three things to consider:

1. Look into `prepareFile`, your input stream may be blocking depending on what you are doing there.
2. Your example also does not account for the possibility of an unchecked `RuntimeException` or `Error` occurring. Since it is not a self-contained program with its own `public static void main() {}`, we can't know whether the program would terminate if, for example, a bad dependency setup here threw a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

   If you don't have an IDE that can show whether this is the case, then just for debugging, you can wrap the whole thing in `} catch (Throwable t) { }` to check. If it is indeed a hang, then you may have OS issues, as you've said.
3. A quick web search shows that some Java users on Mac have seen ImageIO hang when reading from a file, which certainly is strange. You can isolate this further by reading the `FileInputStream` to a `byte` array, and then passing this as `ByteArrayInputStream` to ImageIO, but at this point I would be checking software versions.

   - [ImageIO.read() infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635764/imageio-read-infinite-loop)
   - [Java ImageIO.read causing OSX to hang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780970/java-imageio-read-causing-osx-to-hang)

Comment: I am currently using Eclipse, which doesn't show any confliction - I tried encasing the entire void in the catch you proposed, and still got the same result. Nothing is logged, and no exeptions are thrown that I can see - it just hangs :/

Comment: What would you suggest looking into with my use of 'prepareFile' ?

Comment: I'll try passing to a byte array when i get back home and get back to you :)

Comment: After trying it out, it still hangs on the same line - updated question